# Balance reads in a MongoDB replica set with rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I have a MongoDB as a replica set with one master and one slave. I am using RmongoDB and I want to explicitly send a query to each machine using a parallelized for loop.

I succesfully created a conection with all the hosts:

```
mongo <- mongo.create(host=c("mastermng01:27001","slavemng01:27001"),
                      name="myRS",
                      username="user",
                      password="pass",
                      db="myDB")
ns_actual <- "myDB.MyCollection"
```

Then, I run a query like this:

```
cursor <- mongo.find(mongo,ns=ns_actual,query=list(var1="value"),
                    options=mongo.find.slave.ok)
```

So far, R knows the slave hosts and it is allowed to query them. But when it is going to do it? Can I force R to balance the queries among the hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no solution so far. The underlying C connector is not supporting this functionality. There is a new mongoC library available which supports this. But moving rmongodb to this library will take a lot of time which is currently not available.

Comment: I need to determine which latest version of mongodb does rmongodb supports since I need to authenticate mongo 3 user through rmongodb. Also does it support mongodb 3 ?